# AngularJS $http.post simple method is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I tried to use Angular $http.post(url, data) method. But I am facing some problems to post correct data to server (WebAPI). I have tried follwing options but none is working.

```
var data1 = new Object();
    data1.UserName = "UserA1";
    data1.Password = "password123";
    data1.ConfirmPassword = "password123";

var data2 = angular.toJson(data1);

var data3 = JSON.stringify(data1);

var data4 = { UserName: "UserA2", Password: "password123", ConfirmPassword: "password123" };

var data5 = "UserName=UserA3&Password=password123&ConfirmPassword=password123";

$http.post(url, data1)
$http.post(url, data2)
$http.post(url, data3)
$http.post(url, data4)
$http.post(url, data5)
```

None is working. What kind of data is correct for this method. I tried JQuery.post() with above data and it works. Its super strange for me why this simple angularjs method so hard to use or I am missing something.

Update:
Basically I am working on following example. I want to register user from client side (*/api/Account/Register*).
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

Comment: What does your WebAPI controller method look like?  What response code are you getting?

Comment: What are you using on server side? Is it php?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it's not working? Is the server responding with an error?

Comment: Have you tried Fiddler to see if any web api endpoint even gets hit? The problem seems to be on the server side. Probably some routing issue.

Comment: Server side I am using MVC WebAPI. And I am getting 400 error code in response.

Comment: I tried with Fiddler and everything work as it should be.

Comment: @MohsinJK: Did you find any of the answers below useful ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your server-side expects a request with its content `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

jQuery's `$.post()` sends the request with a Content-type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` whereas Angular's `$http.post()` sends the request with a Content-type of `application/json` (and also encodes the data as JSON (instad of form-data) if a JS Object is passed).

There are methods you can send x-www-form-urlencoded requests using `$http` (and there are several related answers on SO), but it involves less straight-forward code.
I suggest you change your server side to consume JSON requests.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you have on server side, you should transform your request (that's the case for PHP, for example, or you can read from the input stream: php://input).

See this gist: https://gist.github.com/JensRantil/5713606.

If this is not solving your problem, please inspect the requests angular is creating (using the Developer Tools -> Network tab in Chrome for example), and tell us what you see.